# Why does negative rep apply to comments

Tags: bug, reputation

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055115/how-to-pass-form-input-value-to-php-function/15055238#15055238) post, I have down voted a answer, and as suggested/your meant to I left a comment why it could be better. But that negative vote of mine applies to my rep (as I commented), removing 1 rep? Surely it should only apply to the post and author - not the commenters?

Comment: The rep loss wasn't from the comment, it was from the downvote.  Downvoting answers costs -1 rep.

Comment: This should answer your question more completely: [How does “Reputation” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/182513)